# Sending URI data via AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I got some trouble sending long text strings via html forms.

I want to send image data uri to a php page there can handle the data and save it in MySQL.

Image data example:

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfO..

The data is coming from a clipboard paste function I have on the page.

I have no problem in saving the data on the php page, but getting the data to the page makes trouble.

The script below is the one i try use to send the data from the client page:

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append('imagedata','data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfO..');
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php?reportid=1", 
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData
}).done(function(e){
    alert(e);
});
```

It works fine if the image size is small, but if i got an image above 250KB, it loose data during the post.

Maybe someone has a better way to post the data to the server?

Comment: In php.ini, what is upload_max_filesize & post_max_size ?

Comment: both is set to 256M

Comment: Instead of `data: formData` try `data: "imagedata=" + encodeURIComponent('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfO..')`. Other than that, do you randomly lose data or does it cap at a certain byte limit?

Comment: yes i lose data, and it vary, if i use `data: "imagedata=" + encodeURIComponent('data:image....` how should i then receive it on the PHP page? $_POST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternative to transfer the data.

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/3176569) for converting base64 code to blob

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  var byteString;

  if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  else
    byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

  // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ia], {
    type: mimeString
  });
}
```

I change the code to this:

```
formData = new FormData();
var blob = dataURItoBlob('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfO..');

formData.append('imagedata', blob, 'temp.png');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "test.php?reportid=1");
request.send(formData);
```

And then on the PHP page i receive data via $_FILES[];

```
$file = $_FILES['imagedata'];
$filetype = $file['type'];
$blob = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
```

After that, can I insert it into the MySQL database.

Well, thanks anyway for the replies and suggestions :)

Comment: FANTASTIC. I was getting cross origin issues I couldn't solve on my host, transferring to blob and then back on the server for storage worked :) : )

Answer (score -1):

try JSON.parse('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfO..');